# syncing multiple schmeas using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a directory where i defined many mongooose schemas.
for example users.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var users = new mongoose.Schema({
id: String,  // mongoose should create it automatically
username:String,
password:{ type: String, required: true, bcrypt: true },
})

users.plugin(require('mongoose-bcrypt'));

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', users);
```

I want to add all those schemad to DB. so I'm using next file db.js:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

let db = null;

module.exports = app => {
  const config = app.libs.config;
  if (!db) {

      db = mongoose.createConnection(config.host, config.database);
    const dir = path.join(__dirname, "mongoModels");
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
      const model = path.join(dir, file);

      db.models[model.name] = require(model);
    });

  }

  return db;
};
```

but when i try to use those models later in code, i find it undefined.

What i think the problem is - it might be because the models were not synced to db.
I used sequelize in this application before changing to mongo db,
and there i had the following lines:

```
  //app.db.sequelize.sync().done(() => {
    app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
      console.log(`Port ${app.get("port")}`);
      });
//  });
```

as you can see, i commented the sync method which sync all defined schemas to database. is there any way to do the same command in mongoose?
Or of anybody has another idea what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance